# Application quits after attempting to login into online server database

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, authentication

I'm using Android Studio 1.5.1 and I created a login.java and JSONParser.java to connect with 000webhost -> cPanel -> phpmyadmin where I created a database. The code is error free but after I run the application, and I enter the Username and password from the pre-populated database, the application stops.

Here's my Login.java

```
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://mydomain/Login.php"; //replace my domain with my actual domain
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.content_login);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "welcome", 100).show();
    EditTxt_Username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditTxt_Username);
    EditTxt_Password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditTxt_Password);
    Btn_Login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Btn_Login);
    Btn_Login.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
@Override public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.Btn_Login:
         new AttemptLogin().execute();
         // here we have used, switch case, because on login activity you may //also want to show registration button, so if the user is new ! we can go the //registration activity , other than this we could also do this without switch //case.
         default:
             break;
        }
} class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    /** * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog * */
    boolean failure = false;

@Override protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
 pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Attempting for login...");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(true);
    pDialog.show();
}

@Override protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // here Check for success tag int success;
            String username = EditTxt_Username.getText().toString();
    String password = EditTxt_Password.getText().toString();

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Username", username));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password", password));
        Log.d("request!", "starting");
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest( LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);
         // checking log for json response
         Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

    try{
        int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
        if (success == 1) {
            Log.d("Successfully Login!", json.toString());
            Intent ii = new Intent(Login.this,TurnOn.class);
            finish();
            // this finish() method is used to tell android os that we are done with current //activity now! Moving to other activity
            startActivity(ii);
            return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
        }else{ return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } return null;
}
/** * Once the background process is done we need to Dismiss the progress dialog asap * **/
protected void onPostExecute(String message) {
    pDialog.dismiss();
    if (message != null){
       Toast.makeText(Login.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
}
```

Login.php

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("mysql8.000webhost.com","USERNAME","PASSWORD");
    $db= mysql_select_db("DB_NAME");
    $username=$_POST["USERNAME"];
    $password=$_POST["PASSWORD"];

if (!empty($_POST)) {
if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
// Create some data that will be the JSON response
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "One or both of the fields are empty.";
//die is used to kill the page, will not let the code below to be executed. It will also
//display the parameter, that is the json data which our android application will parse to be
//shown to the users
    die(json_encode($response)); }
    $query = " SELECT * FROM login WHERE username = '$username'and password='$password'";
    $sql1=mysql_query($query);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql1);
 if (!empty($row)) {
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "You have been sucessfully logged in!";
    die(json_encode($response));
} else {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Invalid username or password.";
    die(json_encode($response));}
    } else{
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = " One or both of the fields are empty.";
die(json_encode($response));
}

mysql_close();
?>
```

JSONParser.java

```
public class JSONParser {
    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jsonObj ;
    static String json = "";

    // default no argument constructor for jsonpaser class
    public JSONParser() {

    }


    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(final String url) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            // Executing POST request & storing the response from server  locally.
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {


            // Create a BufferedReader
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            // Declaring string builder
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            //  string to store the JSON object.
            String strLine = null;

            // Building while we have string !equal null.
            while ((strLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                str.append(strLine + "\n");
            }

            // Close inputstream.
            is.close();
            // string builder data conversion  to string.
            json = str.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", " something wrong with converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // Try block used for pasrseing String to a json object
        try {
            jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("json Parsering", "" + e.toString());
        }

        // Returning json Object.
        return jsonObj;

    }



    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                      List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Make HTTP request
        try {

            // checking request method
            if(method == "POST"){

                // now defaultHttpClient object
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            String strLine = null;
            while ((strLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                str.append(strLine + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = str.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        // now will try to parse the string into JSON object
        try {
            jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {

        }


        return jsonObj;

    }
```

and here's the logcat

```
03-08 00:28:43.357 2322-2322/com.loyalty4l.myapplication I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
03-08 00:28:43.472 2322-2322/com.loyalty4l.myapplication I/GMPM: App measurement is starting up, version: 8487
03-08 00:28:43.472 2322-2322/com.loyalty4l.myapplication I/GMPM: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.GMPM VERBOSE
03-08 00:28:43.475 2322-2322/com.loyalty4l.myapplication E/GMPM: GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google services.  Possible causes are missing google-services.json or com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin.
03-08 00:28:43.475 2322-2322/com.loyalty4l.myapplication E/GMPM: Scheduler not set. Not logging error/warn.
03-08 00:28:43.485 2322-2338/com.loyalty4l.myapplication E/GMPM: Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
03-08 00:28:43.543 2322-2334/com.loyalty4l.myapplication I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 4470(245KB) AllocSpace objects, 3(48KB) LOS objects, 0% free, 1169KB/1169KB, paused 1.498ms total 110.669ms
03-08 00:28:43.564 2322-2341/com.loyalty4l.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
03-08 00:28:43.575 2322-2322/com.loyalty4l.myapplication D/Atlas: Validating map...
03-08 00:28:43.625 2322-2341/com.loyalty4l.myapplication I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
03-08 00:28:43.639 2322-2341/com.loyalty4l.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
03-08 00:28:43.652 2322-2341/com.loyalty4l.myapplication W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-08 00:28:43.652 2322-2341/com.loyalty4l.myapplication W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xb43f61c0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
03-08 00:28:43.697 2322-2341/com.loyalty4l.myapplication W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-08 00:28:43.697 2322-2341/com.loyalty4l.myapplication W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xb43f61e0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
03-08 00:28:44.287 2322-2322/com.loyalty4l.myapplication I/Choreographer: Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-08 00:29:54.346 2322-2343/com.loyalty4l.myapplication D/request!: starting
03-08 00:29:54.377 2322-2341/com.loyalty4l.myapplication W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-08 00:29:54.377 2322-2341/com.loyalty4l.myapplication W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa4895f60, error=EGL_SUCCESS
03-08 00:29:55.004 2322-2343/com.loyalty4l.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
                                                                           Process: com.loyalty4l.myapplication, PID: 2322
                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
                                                                               at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                                               at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.toString()' on a null object reference
                                                                               at com.example.loyalty4l.myapplication.Login$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(Login.java:79)
                                                                               at com.example.loyalty4l.myapplication.Login$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(Login.java:54)
                                                                               at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                               at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
                                                                               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Did you use Internet permission???   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: **json = str.toString();** remove toString and try to build once..

Comment: @RashiduzzamanKhan yes I did.